# Find and Replace String - Ignore Case and Non-Alpha Characters

Tags: javascript

My website allows users to search the database by keyword. I wrote my server-side search query to ignore special characters and punctuation. So you can search for `story the quick` and find this record: `A story: The quick, brown, fox jumped...`

Next, I'd like to use JavaScript to highlight the words the user searched for on the page. Like this:

Query: *a story the*

Results: ***A story: The*** quick, brown, fox jumped...

---

How can I do this in Javascript? Something like this with some regex, maybe?

```
var query = "a story the";
var res = str.replace(query, "<strong>A story: the</strong>");
```

I spent hours trying to achieve this server-side (PHP), but it is complicated by the fact that the user may or may not include special characters in the query. Essentially, I want to wrap the result `Tes;t` in a `<span>` if the search term was something like `te;!%st` or simply `test`. How can this be done?

**EDIT**

For my purposes, any non-alpha character is considered a "special character" and should be ignored in the query but **included** in the highlighting. Also, I am looking for exact phrases.

For example, if the user has searched `a story the`, I do not want to also highlight every instance of `the`. In theory, searching for `a story &&!@#!@# ___ the` would highlight `a story;__987the`. Meanwhile, any isolated instances of the word `the` should not be highlighted.

Comment: You can simply send the query from the backend to the front end, and in the front-end you receive the variable and simply make a <strong><?php echo $searchWord; ?></strong>... You don't need to complicate, it's very simple. If you want provide some server-side code and front-end as well so that we can help you.

Comment: What other "special characters" are included? How should the application consume the characters? What if they entered "story a quick fox". Should it highlight as "**A story:** The **quick,** brown, **fox,** jumped..." where the commas on both sides of "brown" are highlighted? Or just the one after "quick" and "fox"? You need to be clear about the requirements in the question if you want good answers.

Comment: @HereticMonkey see my updated answer. As I am looking for exact phrases (while ignoring non-alpha characters), searching for "story a quick fox" should not return any results.

Comment: Well, the second sentence of your first paragraph seems to indicate otherwise: "So you can search for `story the quick` and find this record: `A story: The quick, brown, fox jumped...`" Or is that only for the server-side search process? Note that a space is a "non-alpha character"; I'm assuming that spaces mean something different, otherwise "qui ck" would match "quick".